# Calculating the approximate run time of a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, time

I have a piece of code in my C# Windows Form Application that looks like below:

```
List<string> RESULT_LIST = new List<string>();
int[] arr = My_LIST.ToArray();

string s = "";

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
  int counter = i;
  for (int j = 1; j <= arr.Length; j++)
  {
    counter++;
    if (counter == arr.Length)
    {
      counter = 0;
    }
    s += arr[counter].ToString();
    RESULT_LIST.Add(s);
  }
  s = "";
}
sw.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}", ts.TotalMilliseconds * 1000);
MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime);
```

I use this code to get any combination of the numbers of My list. I have behaved with My_LIST like a **recursive** one. The image below demonstrates my purpose very clearly:

[image]

All I need to do is:

> Making a formula to **calculate the approximate run time** of these two
>   nested for loops to guess the run time for any length and help the
>   user know the approximate time that he/she must wait.

I have used a **C# Stopwatch** like this: `Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();` to show the run time and below are the results(Note that in order to reduce the chance of error I've repeated the calculation three times for each length and the numbers show the time in *nano seconds* for the first, second and third attempt respectively.):

1. `arr.Length = 400;`    127838  -  107251  -  100898
2. `arr.Length = 800;`    751282  -  750574  -  739869
3. `arr.Length = 1200;`   2320517 -  2136107 -  2146099
4. `arr.Length = 2000;`   8502631 -  7554743 -  7635173

> Note that there are only **one-digit** numbers in My_LIST to make the time
>   of adding numbers to the list approximately equal.

How can I find out the relation between `arr.Length` and run time?

Comment: All I know the complexity of your code is O(N^2), but the run time depends on your system resources. Finally I think it should be possible to find out that relationship.

Comment: Since your nested loops are both using the same count (`arr.Length`) then the time is going to effectively proportional to that number squared.

Comment: @DavidG I know that, but imagine `arr.Length` is 2500 how many nano seconds would it take to run this code?

Comment: Did you notice that the first attempt is always longer than the other two? Does this pattern hold? Try it a few more times and gather more data. If it does, then *you have reason to believe that the first attempt is atypical*. Now you must decide *what am I actually measuring here*. If your user is likely to run the routine once then you *want* to be measuring the first-run time. If they are calling it thousands of times then you probably want to be discarding the first run time. So which is it?

Comment: @fariba.yazdani Yes I know that but I cannot use it for guessing the time.

Comment: @EricLippert The code may be repeated so many time and all I want is guessing the shortest time period that it takes for the computer to run and finish this code. For example, If `arr.Length` was 2500 what would the time be?

Comment: @mason right here: `string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}", ts.TotalMilliseconds * 1000);`

Comment: i like the other answers and maybe they look easier, just another thought to consider; what i would do is to depend on statistics and a learning machine to calculate the time that maybe taken based on historical learned results. this solution cons is that it is costly such that some learning data may need to be saved somehow. but it depends on how it is important feature to give the estimated time to users. another benefit for this approach is that it is decouples from the system, and can be reused for any piece of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's suppose you have examined the algorithm and noticed that it appears to be quadratic in the array length. This suggests to us that the time taken to run should be a function of the form

t = A + B n + C n<sup>2</sup>

You've gathered some observations by running the code multiple times with different values for n and measuring t. That's a good approach.

The question now is: what are the best values for A, B and C such that they match your observations closely?

This problem can be solved in a variety of ways; I would suggest to you that the least-squares method of regression would be the place to start, and see if you get good results. There's a page on it here:

www.efunda.com/math/leastsquares/lstsqr2dcurve.cfm

---

UPDATE: I just looked at your algorithm again and realized it is cubic because you have a quadratic string concat in the inner loop. So this technique might not work so well.  I suggest you use `StringBuilder` to make your algorithm quadratic.

---

Now, suppose you did *not* know ahead of time that the problem was quadratic. How would you determine the formula then?  A good start would be to graph your points on log scale paper; if they roughly form a straight line then the slope of the line gives you a clue as to the power of the polynomial. If they don't form a straight line -- well, cross that bridge when you come to it.

Comment: You mean every time that a character is added to the end of my string it acts like a for loop to find the last character in my string? Can you explain how I can calculate A, B and C? I'm not that much familiar with regression.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi: String concatenation in C# allocates a new string. So if you have "A" + "B", it allocates "AB".  Then if you add "C", it allocates "ABC". Then if you add "D", it allocates "ABCD".  So we are allocating strings of size 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + .... which gets big fast.  A StringBuilder does not have this problem.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi: This is not a tutorial site. If you are having difficulty writing code to do regression then **do some research**, or watch some videos or get a tutor, or take some classes, or use a tool like Excel or something that has regressions built in.  If you have a *specific question about code* then open up a new question and ask it.

Answer (score 2):

Well you gonna do some math here.

Since the total number of runs is exactly n^2, not O(n^2) but exactly n^2 times.

Then what you could do is to keep a counter variable for the number of items processed and use math to find out an estimate

```
int numItemProcessed;
int timeElapsed;//read from stop watch
int totalItems = n * n;

int remainingEstimate = ((float) totalItems - numItemProcessed) / numItemProcessed) * timeElapsed
```

Comment: That was what I thought at first as well but there is a confounding problem. The string concatenation is quadratic, so we have a quadratic operation in the inner loop. The algorithm as it stands is cubic.

Comment: @EricLippert good point. Using a string builder should solve that problem though

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume the algorithm is necessarily N^2 in time complexity.

Take the averages of your numbers, and plot the best fit on a log-log plot, then measure the gradient. This will give you an idea as to the largest term in the polynomial. (see wikipedia [log-log plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot))

Once you have that, you can do a least-squares regression to work out the coefficients of the polynomial of the correct order. This will allow an estimate from the data, of the time taken for an unseen problem.

Note: As Eric Lippert said, it depends on what you want to measure - averaging may not be appropriate depending on your use case - the first run time might be more correct.

This method will work for any polynomial algorithm. It will also tell you if the algorithm is polynomial (non-polynomial running times will not give straight lines on the log-log plot).

Comment: How can I calculate A, B and  in this regression: A+ B*n + C*(n^2)?